# how to extract each row of a dataframe and add the parsed strings from another dataframe to a column of the first data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
dim <- data.frame(Max = c(1,2,3), Fax = c(4,5,6))
> dim
   Max Fax
 1   1   4
 2   2   5
 3   3   6

min <- data.frame(Num=c(1,2,3), Words = c("ab bc de","ma pa","ka da sa ba"))
> min
    Num       Words
 1   1       ab bc de
 2   2        ma pa
 3   3      ka da sa ba
```

I have two data frames dim amd min. The number of rows in both the data frame are same. Now I want to add another column(Words) to the dim data frame and the dim data frame would look like:

```
> dim

      Max   Fax   Words
 1     1     4     ab
 2     1     4     bc
 3     1     4     de
 4     2     5     ma
 5     2     5     pa
 6     3     6     ka
 7     3     6     da
 8     3     6     sa
 9     3     6     ba
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *think* that it would be more efficient to `merge` first and then split. Here are two options to consider:

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(merge(dim, min, by.x = "Max", by.y = "Num"), key = "Max,Fax")
DT[, list(unlist(strsplit(as.character(Words), " "))), by = key(DT)]
#    Max Fax V1
# 1:   1   4 ab
# 2:   1   4 bc
# 3:   1   4 de
# 4:   2   5 ma
# 5:   2   5 pa
# 6:   3   6 ka
# 7:   3   6 da
# 8:   3   6 sa
# 9:   3   6 ba
```

#### splitstackshape

`concat.split.multiple` from my "splitstackshape" package handles this kind of thing easily (though it is not always the quickest solution).

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(merge(dim, min, by.x = "Max", by.y = "Num"), 
                      "Words", " ", "long")
#    Max Fax time Words
# 1    1   4    1    ab
# 2    2   5    1    ma
# 3    3   6    1    ka
# 4    1   4    2    bc
# 5    2   5    2    pa
# 6    3   6    2    da
# 7    1   4    3    de
# 8    2   5    3  <NA>
# 9    3   6    3    sa
# 10   1   4    4  <NA>
# 11   2   5    4  <NA>
# 12   3   6    4    ba
```

You can use `complete.cases` if you want to get rid of the `NA` values in the output from `concat.split.multiple`.

Comment: Hi am really sorry to confuse u...I forgot to mention one thing that in actual my dim df has around 5000 columns and min  df has around 4.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Fax = 6 for the last 4 columns? If so, this is maybe not the most elegant solution, but it should do the job:

```
tmp2 <- apply(min, 1, function(x) {
  tmp <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[2]), " "))
  data.frame(Num = rep(x[1], length(tmp)), Words = tmp)})

min <- do.call(rbind, tmp2)

dim <- merge(dim, min, by.x = "Max", by.y = "Num", all = TRUE)

dim

  Max Fax Words
1   1   4    ab
2   1   4    bc
3   1   4    de
4   2   5    ma
5   2   5    pa
6   3   6    ka
7   3   6    da
8   3   6    sa
9   3   6    ba
```

What I did I applied strsplit on Words and remade your min data.frame. After that merge function works well to put the data frames together.

Comment: ya..it will be 6 instead of 4.

Comment: Hi am really sorry to confuse u...I forgot to mention one thing that in actual my dim df has around 5000 columns and min  df has around 4.

Comment: @tanay It is difficult to understand what you want. Both of the answers here solve your current question, so you should accept one or if you are not satisfied update your question.